# How do I send a variable via GET Request between 2 php pages

Tags: php, html, get

In my program, I have a table Artists in my database with an ID, name, and gender. I am trying to create 2 PHP pages.

- The first page prints the name of all artists and their genders.
- I want to hyperlink every name on the first page, to the second page. So whenever I click the artist, the ID is sent to the second page.
- I will use the ID to compare to another table to print out some other information.

I am trying to perform the above procedure using GET. However, my code isn't working. The value I am trying to send is row[artist_id] ie, $id.

**First PHP Page**
......

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, gender,artist_id FROM artists '
                 . ' ORDER BY name ASC, artist_id ASC';
          $result = $pdo->query($sql);
          echo "<table>";
          echo "<tr><th>Artist name</th><th>Gender</th></tr>";
          foreach ($result as $row) {
             echo "<tr>";
             $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
             $gender = htmlspecialchars($row['gender']);
             $id = $row['artist_id'];
             echo "<td><a href='artist_events.php'?val=$id>".$name."</a></td>";
             echo"<td>".$gender."</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
```

**Second PHP Page**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
table,th,td{
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
    <title>My second PHP page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      include 'config.php';
    ?>
    <?php
    $my_id= $_GET['val'];
    echo $my_id;

    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: `$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name, gender,artist_id FROM artists WHERE id= :id);`                
 `$sql->execute(['id'=>my_id]);`                                                                    
 `$result=$sql->fetchObject();`

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I want to send the ID to another php page where I will use it to compare it with another table. I only want to print the names/ genders on page 1.

Comment: try this. `echo "<td><a href='artist_events.php'?val=".$id.">".$name."</a></td>";`

Comment: Is gender being stored as a boolean or varchar?

Comment: @JasonMetr It would have been better if you had explained in  the question what went wrong exactly. "my code isn't working" is not a very good problem description.

Comment: @MrLister The problem is, I don't know where exactly I'm wrong. Like I said, I'm having trouble sending $id from the first page to the second.

Comment: @JasonMetr Are you able to receive the $id on the next page and see it?

Comment: @Gopal Sharma, It just goes to the next page. I don't see the ID on the URL or the page.

Comment: @JasonMetr So you do see a list of links on the screen that you can click? That wasn't clear in  the question. You should edit that in. Also, what does the source of the page look like.

Comment: @JasonMetr Could you please share any url that is generated on the first page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<td><a href='artist_events.php'?val=$id>".$name."</a></td>";
```

The issue is with this line. You have closed the href attribute before passing the GET parameter.

Change it to

```
echo "<td><a href='artist_events.php?val=$id'>".$name."</a></td>";
```

I have changed the position of closing quotes for href attribute.

Comment: this change that i made doesn't have anything to do with the printing of the tables. can you be more clear on your issue you are facing after making this change.

Comment: Sorry! I missed a ". It still doesn't seem to be sending the value to the second page. I don't see it on the URL nor is it printed on the second page

Comment: I tried your edited answer and it seems to be working now. Thanks!